# q-differentiability in $R_q$

Tags: derivatives, quantum-calculus

Wokring in q-calculus where everything is defined on the set $$R_q =\{\pm q^k,k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ 0\}$$
In which they define the q-derivative (or q-difference operator) as
$$D_qf(x)=\frac{f(x)−f(qx)}{(1−q)x}, \quad x\neq 0$$
$$D_qf(x)=f'(0), \quad x=0 $$
My question is, what is meant by q-differentialbe here as the only singularity is at $x=0$ which is excluded. Then every function should be q-differentiable or not?

Comment: q-differentiability isn't meaningfully defined on its own. It's only when, for example: we take the limit as $q \rightarrow 1$, that we say it is 'differentiable'

Comment: Also note that: $$D_qf(x)=f'(x), \quad x=0 $$ doesn't make much sense. Rather it should be
$$\lim_{q \rightarrow 1}D_qf(x) = f'(x)$$

Comment: Sorry, I mean that $D_qf(x)=f'(0)$ at $x=0$.